# Can odata total records be found without fetching them?

Tags: odata

Am creating paging and fetching 10 JSON records per page:

```
  var coursemodel = query.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
```

I need to display on the web page the total number of records available in database. For example, you are viewing 20 to 30 of x (where x is total number of records). Can x be found without transferring the records over the network?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorted it. Did this

`http://yourserver7:40479/odata/Courses?$top=1&skip=1&$inlinecount=allpages`

Got this

```
 {
  "odata.metadata":"http://yourserver7:40479/odata/$metadata#Courses","odata.count":"503","value":[
    {
      "CourseID":20,"Name":"Name 20","Description":"Description 20","Guid":"Guid 20"
    }
  ]
}
```

I then got the value from odata.count! My url gets all records found, add $filter where applicable...

Comment: The query parameter `$inlinecount` is not supported with OData 4.0. Your answer related to early version of OData.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `$count` operator to return the total number of records, something along these lines:

```
http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Categories(1)/Products/$count
```

Not sure what the syntax would be with Linq, but pretty sure it is possible.

PS - Always a good reference: http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/

Comment: Thank you for reply. It looks like the only way of finding the total records in dbase table is to use a web.api count endpoint

Comment: http://localhost:40479/odata/Courses?$inlinecount=allpages this gives the count value in the metadata, but I don't know how to access it in c#

Comment: Are you calling it through a service reference? Not sure what you mean by having to access it in c#.

Comment: Yes, am calling a c# web service (odata) from c# mvc application. I want to implement manual paging (not pagedlist...) and am using skip and take. As I fetch each set of json records across network the paging info needs to display the total number of records available. Doing a count from each take only displays the total for that set of records (eg if take is 10 then total is 10!!). I need to know the overall number of records found by the odata query...I need to display to user something like this 'Viewing 20-30 of 100. How do you find the total, eg 100?

Comment: This is what I need: http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/extending-your-asp-net-web-api-responses-with-useful-metadata/ It gives total records available (not total for present fetch). I am using all latest versions of software (eg Visual Studio 2013). Does anyone know if the info on the strathweb site can be implemented more easlily with later versions of software? (eg  web.api 2.1 etc)

Comment: @Steve I understand what you are trying to accomplish, what I am asking is how you are trying to get the information? Are you using a Service Reference? Or are you using an HttpClient?

Comment: Hi Schandlich, yes using service reference. This is code:  Uri uri = new Uri("http://server/WebApi/odata");             var container = new CourseService.Container(uri);
            var query = container.Courses.Where(c => c.Description == searchparameter); //Start to construct query...

Comment: For OData 4, I had to use $count=true (Count alone threw errors) -- but even then it just gave me the total for the first page, not for the whole dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I added a &count=true to the query string and it returns a "@odata.count": 14 before the vaule object.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
context.EFCars.Where(c => c.Description == desc).Count();
```

Where EFCars is an entity set name.