# Asp.net Core OData using pagination cant seem to find how to get total record count

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

I am trying to page with OData however it seems the dataset returned does not have the totalitems for the complete set being queried.

I have looked on SO in a number questions - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22721038/can-odata-total-records-be-found-without-fetching-them), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56221207/odata-in-net-core-2-2-how-to-get-total-number-of-items) and C# Corner has [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/paging-with-odata-and-Asp-Net-web-api/) tutorial on OData with Asp.Net Core.

When you do pagination its my understanding that you need to specify start and skip and total item count etc. From what I am reading Asp.net Core OData does not have `inlinecount`as a query option.

If this is the case how on earth do you get the total item count with a page set?

I have the following in startup.cs:

```
        app.UseMvc(routeBuilder => {
            routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
            routeBuilder.Expand().Select().OrderBy().Filter().MaxTop(null).Count().Expand();
```

I have, in my controller:

```
   [HttpGet("Index", Name = "ClientIndex")]
   [EnableQuery()]
    public IQueryable<Client> GetClients() {
        return _context.Clients;
    }
```

and the query as it stands is:

```
http://localhost:57500/#clients/clientsList?$top=10&$orderby=ClientNo asc,ClientLastName asc,MobilePhone asc
```

So, in order to successfully implement pagination I need the total records in the database table yet it appears that you cannot obtain the this value in response..

Answer (score 0):

Using $count instead of $inlinecount.

Here is the response:
[image]

[image]

Visit this link https://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/#count to refer more, my friend.

Here is a sample. Hope to help, my friend :))

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData -Version 7.1.0

--Models--

```
public class Product
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

--Controller--

```
public class ProductsController : ODataController
    {
        private List<Product> products = new List<Product>()
        {
            new Product()
            {
                ID = 1,
                Name = "Bread",
            },
            new Product()
            {
                ID = 2,
                Name = "Tomato",
            },
            new Product()
            {
                ID = 3,
                Name = "Lemon",
            },new Product()
            {
                ID = 4,
                Name = "Orange",
            }
        };

        [EnableQuery]
        public List<Product> Get()
        {
            return products;
        }
    }
```

--Startup---

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc(option => 
            {
                option.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
            }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);            
            services.AddOData();
        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }            

            var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(app.ApplicationServices);

            builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");

            app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
            {                
                routeBuilder.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(100).Count();
                routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());                
                routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
            });            

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've already tried that and it does indeed return the count but in this case if I am getting the say the top 10 records count comes back with 10 not 30 thats in the whole collection in the database. In order to do pagination I need total number of records not the count of the records in the returned data. In fact that very page says "request a count of the matching resources included with the resources in the response.".. so I need total items in the table eg clients.

Comment: @si2030: Hi, my friend. Could you post your case? Because when I run the request: https://localhost:44352/odata/Products?$skip=2&$top=3&$count=true, it really returns the value of whole collection.

Comment: This is the query I used: 'http://localhost:57500/api/client/index?&$count=true&$top=10&$orderby=ClientNo asc,ClientLastName asc,MobilePhone asc'. Still dont get totalItemCount. Is this to with Asp.net Core not being able to supply this option?

Comment: @si2030: Hi, my friend. I used Web Api with .Net core 2.2 for a sample. Asp.net Core really supports get a total count. Could you post a picture that shows the response with your request? See my picture above.

Comment: @si2030: If your task is extremely necessary, you can push your code to github. So I can help better, my friend :))